# Is there any way to distinguish between window.print, File->Print and Ctrl+P events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

In my app I need to treat the print event differently for each scenario.
I've tried doing so by comparing the events in a 'beforeprint' listener, but they seem to be equal.

Is there a way to find out what caused this print event? Preferably in the event listener.

Thank you!

Comment: I dont think there is a way to distinguish this based on the event. You can capture the ctrl+p keypress and do your logic before running `window.print` but i dont think this can be done for file->print.

Comment: You could make assumptions by using `window.print()` override and `onkeyup`, yet you will never know for sure.

Comment: Thanks! I will use the keyboard event that was fired before to identify the scenario.